# Returning array of character error in c++?

Tags: c++

I have these two files *table.cpp* and *table.h* in my program code apart from the *main.cpp*. The files are described as below

***table.cpp***

```
#include <iostream>
#include "table.h"

using namespace std;

// accessor function for Name
char* PeriodicTable::Name()
{
    return Name;
}

// accessor function for Symbol
char* PeriodicTable::Symbol()
{
    return Symbol;
}
```

***table.h***

```
#ifndef TABLE_H
#define TABLE_H

class PeriodicTable
{
    char Name[15], Symbol[3], GroupName[20], Block, State[25], Colour[15], Classification[20];
    int GroupNo, AtomicNo, PeriodNo;
    float Weight;

public:

    char* Name();
    char* Symbol();


};

#endif
```

but the problem is that the IntelliSense(since I am using Visual C++ Express 2010) shows a **red curved underline** below the *name* and *symbol* in the accessor function in *table.cpp*. I can't understand why???

Comment: "Intelli"sense is a big name... does it compile / link OK? As an aside I don't like having variables and functions with the same name...

Comment: IntelliSense is thinking you're returning a reference to a function. Btw, if you hold your mouse over that little red squiggly, it will tell you this.

Comment: You should move your `#include <iostream>` statement from your .cpp to your .h file.

Comment: @ThomasBenard: You should **not**, why would you?

Comment: VS 2010 and above use the [EDG](http://www.edg.com/) compiler front-end for IntelliSense. This is not some ghetto tool. If it throws red squiggles at you it's a good idea to hover your mouse over it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your member functions and member variables have the same name. This is not possible in C++. That's why various conventions exist for naming member variables, e.g. `m_name`, `name_` etc. (NB: When dealing with underscores in identifiers make sure you don't use a reserved name by accident.)

You might wonder why and how that could possibly go wrong. In your example there clearly is no way to invoke `operator()` on `char[15]`, but the problem is that the compiler only knows that after performing semantic analysis. There could also be cases where it is impossible to disambiguate. For example:

```
struct Func {
  void operator()() { };
};

struct C {
  Func f;
  void f() {}
};

int main() {
  C c;
  c.f(); // which one?
}
```